# jquery: How do i set First "child" visible in Tree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In this Tree I'm trying to Make "child Visible when page loads but it's not Working properly please help me out on this...

```
$('.tree li:First').show();
```

This make Parent visible while i want to visible it's direct childs 
[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/fXzHS/317/)

Comment: The jsfiddle you provide is not using "$('.tree li:First').show();". It's using "$('ul:nth-child(2)').show()" (note that is a missing semicolon). If you replace that an put "$('.tree li:First').show();" instead, it would be running just fine, al least it's works for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apply a `class` for the direct child 
like,

```
<li class="child"><a href="#">Child</a></li>
```

Java Script code:

```
$(function () {
    $('.tree li').hide();    
    $('.tree li:First').show();
    $('.child').show();
    $('.tree li').on('click', function (e) {
        var children = $(this).find('> ul > li');
        if (children.is(":visible")) children.hide('fast');
        else children.show('fast');
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

see : [<kbd>demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/Sa2hq/)

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$('.tree li:first-child').show();
```

updated code

```
$(function () {
$('.tree li').hide();    
$('.tree li:first-child').show();
$('.tree li').on('click', function (e) {
    var children = $(this).find('> ul > li');
    if (children.is(":visible")) children.hide('fast');
    else children.show('fast');
    e.stopPropagation();
});
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fXzHS/321/)

**Edit**

```
$(function () {
$('.tree li').hide();    

$('.tree li:first-child').show();
 $('.tree ul:eq(1)').find("ul").hide();

$('.tree li').on('click', function (e) {
    var children = $(this).find('> ul > li');
    if (children.is(":visible")) children.hide('fast');
    else children.show('fast');
    e.stopPropagation();
 });
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fXzHS/320/)

Comment: this is wrong this display first child with all child. his question is only display  all first child not to display all the step child.

Comment: oh no no you're not getting I think... I want both child of Parent node visible not single child